# Changing Axis Web Service's URL

Tags: java, web-services, url, webserver, axis

I'm creating a web service with Axis and used AdminClient at runtime to deploy my web service at runtime. After running my java file I can access my web service with this URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8099/axis/services/MyWebService .
```

I want to know how can I change the URL of my web service deployed with axis at runtime.
I want to change that URL as

```
http://127.0.0.1:8099/MyWebService (OR) http://127.0.0.1:8099 .
```

How can I do that? Any advice?

Here is my code.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.axis.transport.http.SimpleAxisServer;

public class AxisTest {

    // start SimpleAxisServer
    public AxisTest(){        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            int port = 8099;
            SimpleAxisServer server = new SimpleAxisServer();

            System.out.println("Opening server on port: "+ port);

            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            ss.setSoTimeout(10000);
            server.setServerSocket(ss);

            server.start();
            System.out.println("Starting server...");

            // Read the deployment description of the service

            String deploymenDescriptorFileName = "deploy.wsdd";
            InputStream deploymentDescriptorStream = new     FileInputStream(deploymenDescriptorFileName); 

            // Now deploy our  web service            
            org.apache.axis.client.AdminClient adminClient;

            adminClient = new org.apache.axis.client.AdminClient();

            System.out.println("Deploying receiver server web service...");
            String process = adminClient.process(
                    new org.apache.axis.utils.Options(new String[] {"-ddd","-tlocal"}), 
                    deploymentDescriptorStream);
            System.out.println("Process : "+process);
            System.out.println("Server started. Waiting for connections on: " + port);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AxisTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can call my WSDL by http://127.0.0.1:8099/axis/services/MyWebService?wsdl

Comment: Then, you can edit the endpoint of the service in it.

Answer (score 1):

`stringy05` answer was almost true. Yes, you can find it [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html).

To get what you want you should add `<parameter name="axis.servicesPath" value="/"/>`

And as it was said in tutorial:

> Path to the Axis servlet. This should be the same as the services
>   servlet-mapping defined in web.xml. Used for displaying the list of
>   services. Default is "/services/"

You should modify your `web.xml` as follows:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the wsdd file, from http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html

```
<service name="MyServiceName" 
        provider="java:RPC" 
        style="rpc|document|wrapped" 
        use="encoded|literal"
        streaming="off|on"
        attachment="MIME|DIME|NONE">

 <parameter name="className" value="org.apache.mystuff.MyService"/>
 <parameter name="allowedMethods" value="method1 method2 method3"/>
 <parameter name="wsdlTargetNamespace" value="http://mystuff.apache.org/MyService"/>
 <parameter name="wsdlServiceElement" value="MyService"/>
 <parameter name="wsdlServicePort" value="MyServicePort"/>
 <parameter name="wsdlPortType" value="MyPort"/>
 <parameter name="wsdlSoapActionMode" value="NONE|DEFAULT|OPERATION"/>

 <parameter name="SingleSOAPVersion" value="1.1|1.2/>

 <documentation>Service level info</documentation>

 <endpointURL>http://example.com:5050/my/custom/url/to/service</endpointURL>

 <wsdlFile>/path/to/wsdl/file</wsdlFile>
 <namespace>http://my.namespace.com/myservice</namespace>
 <handlerInfoChain>handlerChainName</handlerInfoChain>

 <operation ... />

 <typeMapping ... />

 <beanMapping ... />

</service>
```

Comment: I added the endpoint as you suggested like . It's changed in wsdl file also but I can't access

Comment: I added the endpoint as you suggested like <endpointURL>http://localhost:8099/MyWebService</endpointURL>. It's changed in wsdl file also but I can't access to http://localhost:8099/MyWebService it's show message as "The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke!  targetService is null"

Answer (score 0):

I will explain how I am doing the same in my code.
I have two classes: Publisher and Deployer.
-Publisher publishes(creates the WSDLs etc)-here we mention the URL
-Deployer deploys them on the URL given in publisher.

In Publisher I am passing the URL(custom made) as one of the arguments.

Publisher Code:- **The publisher class should extend Java2WSDL**. And it should have a arg-constructor where we would be setting the custom WSDL file name, URL for webservices etc. Add these elements to a List, and pass the list as argument to "**super.run(list)**"

Sample argument to be passed in the run() method of Publisher.java from its main() method:-

```
-o, D:\MyProject\WSAD\Workspace\Webservices\JavaSource\SampleWebserviceSpi.wsdl, -l, http://localhost:8086/Webservices/SampleWebserviceSpi, -y, WRAPPED, -u, LITERAL, -d, com.org.spi.ISampleWebserviceSpi, -P, SampleWebserviceSpi, -i, com.org.spi.SampleWebserviceSpi]
```

So, this is how you can publish a custom made web-service.

Now to deploy them :-
Deployer.java should extend **org.apache.axis.client.AdminClient** class.
Sample arguments to be passed in the "**super.process(list)**" from its main() method:-

```
[-l, http://localhost:8086/Webservices/servlet/AxisServlet, D:\MyProject\Workspace\Webservices\WebContent\wsdd\.\SampleWebservice.wsdd]
```

I didn't provide every detail in code.
Hope this helps.